# How to fix a slanted axis in Tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, graphs

I have attempted to create a limacon with the equation r= 0.5 + cos(theta).

```
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[h!]
    \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    [xscale=3, yscale=3, domain=0:2*pi]
    \draw[<->](-0.2,0)--(1.7,0) node[above]{$x$};
    \draw[<->](-1,0)--(0,1) node[right]{$y$};
    \draw[color=blue, smooth] 
    plot({0.5*cos(\x r) + cos(\x r)*cos(\x r)}, {0.5*sin(\x r) + sin(\x r)*cos(\x r)});
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \caption{Graph of $r= 0.5 + \mathrm{cos}\theta$}
    \label{Limacon}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

This produces the graph I want but my y axis is slanted to the left. How would I fix this?
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Looks like a simple coordinate problem:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[h!]
    \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    [xscale=3, yscale=3, domain=0:2*pi]
    \draw[<->](-0.2,0)--(1.7,0) node[above]{$x$};
    \draw[<->](0,-1)--(0,1) node[right]{$y$}; % <-- here
    \draw[color=blue, smooth]
    plot({0.5*cos(\x r) + cos(\x r)*cos(\x r)}, {0.5*sin(\x r) + sin(\x r)*cos(\x r)});
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \caption{Graph of $r= 0.5 + \mathrm{cos}\theta$}
    \label{Limacon}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]